# gpg: processing message failed: eof ;Error Unix ksh GPG decryption Script

Tags: unix, ksh, gnupg

I am new to Unix and ksh script writing. I wrote a script that decrypts a gpg message. I get this error that I do not know how to resolve. I was hoping someone could look at my script and help me figure out what is going on. Thank you for any assistance you can provide. 
Here is the error:

```
gpg: processing message failed: eof
```

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/ksh
####################################################################       
#   1. Decrypt Inbound File                                        #
#                                                                  #
#   Two parms are required:   output file                          #
#                             encrypted file(to be decrypted)      #
#                                                                  #
####################################################################
# Variable declaration                                             #
####################################################################
outputF=$1 
encryptedF=$2
id=$$
####################################################################
# print_message                                                    #
#    prints messages to log file                                   #
####################################################################
print_message()
{
   message="$1"
   echo "`date '+%m-%d-%y %T'`  $message" 

}
#####################################################################
# Validate input parameters and existence of encrypted file         #
#####################################################################

if [ $1 -eq ""] ||  [ $2 -eq ""]
    then 
    print_message "Parameters not satisfied"

    exit 1 
fi 

if [ ! -f $encryptedF ]
then
   print_message "$id ERROR: $encryptedF File does not exist"
   exit 1
fi

#####################################################
#               Decrypt encryptedF                  #
#####################################################

gpg --output "$outputF" --decrypt "$encryptedF"

echo "PASSPHRASE" | gpg --passphrase-fd 0 

print_message "$id INFO: File Decrypted Successfully"
```

Comment: You wrote: `I get this error that I do not know how to resolve`... Please edit your message to include the exact text of the error message. As you have discovered, use the `{}` edit tool to keep the format of the message. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter updated, do you think you can help?

Comment: please edit your question to show which line with `gpg` you are executing. All the other code looks fine, I would delete that, and post only the simpliest test case for `gpg`. ..... I'm not sure how I can help, given what I know about unix processes in general, I would have expected your 2 commands to be merged into one, AND for the output of `gpg` to be sent somewhere: a redirect file like `gpg ... > unecryptedFile` OR assigned  to shell variable like `myUnecryptedOutput=$(gpg .... )`. Can you update to include expected output of using some simple phrase of input? Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a gpg problem :-)  Your script tries to run the gpg binary twice. The first call tries to decode the file:

```
gpg --output "$outputF" --decrypt "$encryptedF"
```

Since no means of passphrase input is given, gpg tries to read the passphrase from the console. What now happens, depends on your gpg configuration, ksh behaviour, etc., but I suspect interaction with STDIN is somehow crippled, resulting in the EOF error.

The solution of your problem: You have to add the passphrase source to the decryption call:

```
echo "PASSPHRASE" | gpg --passphrase-fd 0 --output "$outputF" --decrypt "$encryptedF"
```